# React useState Object not getting using variable but variable-name when updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I have a function that should update an React useState Object, but instead of the key-value the "key-name" gets inserted into the Object. What I want is to replace one value in the Object with a new one depending on the inputIndex (number between 1-4). What have I done wrong?

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
  1:"80/static\\images\\00205.png",
  2:"80/static\\images\\00206.png",
  3:"80/static\\images\\00207.png",
  4:"80/static\\images\\00210.png"
});
const set = (inputIndex) =>{
  setSelected({...selected, inputIndex:"80/static\\images\\0001.png"})
}
```

The output after the "const set" is called:

```
{1: '80/static\\images\\00205.png', 2: '80/static\\images\\00206.png', 3: '80/static\\images\\00207.png', 4: '80/static\\images\\00210.png', inputIndex: 'http://85.229.133.157:80/static\\images\\00210.png'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) as `{[prop_name]: val}`

```
const set = (inputIndex) =>{
  setSelected({...selected, [inputIndex]:"80/static\\images\\0001.png"})
}
```